# Combine two bytes from gyroscope into signed angular rate

Tags: c, byte, signed

I've got two 8-bit chars. They're the product of some 16-bit signed float being broken up into MSB and LSB inside a gyroscope.

The standard method I know of combining two bytes is this:

`(signed float) = (((MSB value) << 8) | (LSB value));`

Just returns garbage.

How can I do this?

Comment: 16-bit float? Is that possible?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you swap the bytes?  Also, keep in mind, you have two bytes there, and float is 4 bytes on most systems. What did you do with the other two bytes of the original float you deconstructed?  Consider saving those and using those :-)

Comment: Floats are not like 2's compliment integers.  They are complex IEEE standard.  You probably actually need all 4 bytes of the original float to reconstruct a sensible floating point number.

Comment: Without knowing how they were "broken up" and/or seeing an example, it's difficult to say what the correct behaviour is here.  But one thing's for sure, you need to be reinterpreting the bits, and your code isn't doing that.

Comment: Perhaps you've gotten the endianness swapped? Or you have to cast to `unsigned char`?

Comment: I posted an answer below that shows a diagram of how a float is laid out. That shows the exact bits the essential and less important bits of the float are in.  You could potentially drop some of the fractional component and still get a usable number I think, but you need to place the subcomponents back properly to get a useful result.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2: Oh my, what a lovely two, you look gorgeous today.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it isn't my base 2 I'm going on about :-) But thanks just the same.

Comment: Floats don't have MSB or LSB, and aren't 16 bits wide either. It sound to me like what you really have is a 16-bit signed short.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits  [Half-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @EJP floats do have an endian order. MSB/LSB is not a wholly incorrect way to express the 2 bytes.

Comment: DC177E, provide some information about the 16-bit float format that you are using or at least some sample byte/float combinations.  As it stands, without more info, this post lacks usefulness.  Is it [binary16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, dear me from ~4 years ago:

First of all, the gyroscope you're working with is a [MAX21000](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX21000.pdf). The datasheet, as far as future you can see, doesn't actually describe the endianness of the I2C connection, which probably also tripped you up. However, the SPI connection does state that the data is transmitted MSB-first, with the top 8-bits of the axis data in the first byte, and the additional 8 in the next.

To your credit, the datasheet doesn't really go into what type those 16 bits represent - however, that's because it's standardized across manufacturers.

The real reason why you got such meaningless values when converting to float is that *the gyro isn't sending a float*. Why'd you even think it would?

The gyro sends a plain 'ol int16 (short). A simple search for "i2c gyro interface" would have made that clear. How do you get that into a decimal angular rate? You divide by 32,768 (int16's max positive value), then multiply by the full-scale range set on the gyro.

Simple! Here, want a code example?

> float X_angular_rate = ((((int16_t)((byte_1 << 8) | byte_2))/SHRT_MAX)*GYRO_SCALE

However, I think that it's important to note that the data from these gyroscopes alone is not, in itself, as useful as you thought; to my current knowledge, due to their poor zero-rate drift characteristics, MEMS gyros are almost always used in a sensor fusion setup with an accelerometer and a Kalman filter to make a proper IMU.

Any position and attitude derived from dead-reckoning without this added complexity is going to be hopelessly inaccurate after mere minutes, which is why you added an accelerometer to the next revision of the board.

Answer (score -1):

You have shown two bytes, and float is 4 bytes on most systems. What did you do with the other two bytes of the original float you deconstructed? You should preserve and re-construct all four original bytes if possible. If you can't, and you have to omit any bytes, set them to zero, and make them the least significant bits in the fractional part of the float and hopefully you'll get an answer with satisfactory precision.

The diagram below shows the bit positions, so acting in accordance with the endianness of your system, you should be able to construct a valid float based on how you deconstructed the original.  It can really help to write a function to display values as binary numbers and line them up and display initial, intermediate and end results to ensure that you're really accomplishing what you think (hope) you are.

[image]

To get a valid result you have to put something sensible into those bits.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Best not to model down votes as "punitive"; they're simply to reflect that the corresponding answer isn't useful (in this case, doesn't answer the question).

Comment: There is; just link to the wiki page.

Comment: OK, I could but it still seems to me like a better way to show a picture, so someone reviewing the thread can just instantly see the picture which is worth a 1000 words and understand exactly what the score is.

Comment: Perhaps, rather than downvoting this answer simply because he has done *some* of the research for the OP, you could downvote the *question* because @DC177E seems to have done insufficient research to bring this (among other important details) up in the question himself.

Comment: This actually does help a lot, I think I'll be able to piece together what I need from this; however, my float only has 2 bytes.